# I want to start the switch/case loop only when value change

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am running `switch` `case` loop to take the value of setpoint to send it to my AC to change the temperature set point but the loop is contiuosly running what I want to activate the switch loop only if ESP8266 get the new value of setpoint.

here is my code what I m using:

```
     int set = root["set_point"];
     switch(set) {

       case 31:
       Serial.println("SET TEMP 31");
       break;
       case 30:
       Serial.println("SET TEMP 30");
       break;
       case 29:
       Serial.println("SET TEMP 29");
       break;

     }




     }
```

Any solution for it!

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to save last value for `set` and check with the new one if it changes then go for `switch` case.

```
int set_last_value = 0;
int set = 0;

void setup()
{
    // ...
}

void loop()
{
    if ((set = root["set_point"]) != set_last_value)
    {
        switch (set)
        {
        case 31:
            Serial.println("SET TEMP 31");
            break;
        case 30:
            Serial.println("SET TEMP 30");
            break;
        case 29:
            Serial.println("SET TEMP 29");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        set_last_value = set;
    }
}
```